# Casting pointer to unrelated type

Tags: c, strict-aliasing

I'm currently trying to get hang of C strict-aliasing rules and this code by my current understanding is violating them.

We have converted buffer pointer to struct setup pointer and by C standard it should lead to undefined behavior, right?

```c
static inline void libusb_fill_control_transfer(
    struct libusb_transfer *transfer, libusb_device_handle *dev_handle,
    unsigned char *buffer, libusb_transfer_cb_fn callback, void *user_data,
    unsigned int timeout)
{
    struct libusb_control_setup *setup = (struct libusb_control_setup *)(void *) buffer;
    transfer->dev_handle = dev_handle;
    transfer->endpoint = 0;
    transfer->type = LIBUSB_TRANSFER_TYPE_CONTROL;
    transfer->timeout = timeout;
    transfer->buffer = buffer;
    if (setup)
        transfer->length = (int) (LIBUSB_CONTROL_SETUP_SIZE
            + libusb_le16_to_cpu(setup->wLength));
    transfer->user_data = user_data;
    transfer->callback = callback;
}
```

Edit.

This is part of libusb project https://github.com/libusb/libusb/blob/7ffad5c137ed4c1d8a3ac485f35770fb979ca53a/libusb/libusb.h#L1578

Edit 2.

Adding `libusb_control_setup` struct definition

```
struct libusb_control_setup {
    /** Request type. Bits 0:4 determine recipient, see
     * \ref libusb_request_recipient. Bits 5:6 determine type, see
     * \ref libusb_request_type. Bit 7 determines data transfer direction, see
     * \ref libusb_endpoint_direction.
     */
    uint8_t  bmRequestType;

    /** Request. If the type bits of bmRequestType are equal to
     * \ref libusb_request_type::LIBUSB_REQUEST_TYPE_STANDARD
     * "LIBUSB_REQUEST_TYPE_STANDARD" then this field refers to
     * \ref libusb_standard_request. For other cases, use of this field is
     * application-specific. */
    uint8_t  bRequest;

    /** Value. Varies according to request */
    uint16_t wValue;

    /** Index. Varies according to request, typically used to pass an index
     * or offset */
    uint16_t wIndex;

    /** Number of bytes to transfer */
    uint16_t wLength;
};
```

Comment: That depends on the content of `struct libusb_control_setup` and it also depends on where the pointer `buffer` came from, i.e. what type of object it is pointing to. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: It's actually part of libusb code https://github.com/libusb/libusb/blob/7ffad5c137ed4c1d8a3ac485f35770fb979ca53a/libusb/libusb.h#L1578 and I don't have any exact usage. I'm just curious about validity from the C standard's point of view. Obviously code works,but by my current understanding it violates aliasing rule.

Comment: It is no doubt "undefined behavior", but if `buffer` satisfies all alignment requirements of `struct libusb_transfer`, I am yet to see a case where decoding a buffer like this actually fails. It is often not possible to use the `memcpy()` construct without it resulting in suboptimal binary code. My guess is that `libusb` developers have taken a pragmatic choice here.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the parameter `buffer` doesn't actually point to an object of type `struct libusb_control_setup` (probably an `unsigned char` array?), then yes this is a strict aliasing violation which is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The rules governing aliasing are specified in section 6.5p7 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
> expression that has one of the following types:<sup>88)</sup>
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a
>   subaggregate or contained union), or
> - a character type.
>
> ---
>
> 88 ) The intent of this list is to specify those circumstances in
> which an object may or may not be aliased.

Note that this does not include treating a `char` array as if it were some other type, although the reverse is allowed.

The proper way to handle this is to create a local structure of the given type, then use `memcpy` to copy the bytes over.

```
struct libusb_control_setup setup;
memcpy(&setup, buffer, sizeof setup);
```

Comment: The buffer is most likely coming from char buffer. 
Regarding the provided example, that's how I would have done it, but since this is code from respectable project which is obviously used in a lot of places I'm not sure what to think about it.

Comment: Also why would it matter to what the `unsigned char* buffer` pointer points to?
Shouldn't it be possible to reason locally just by looking at the body of the function.

Comment: "Shouldn't it be possible to reason locally" No.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I have included the definition of struct to which the character buffer is begin cast to.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: The `unsigned char *` used to pass the address of the buffer is irrelevant (it may be the result of a cast); the original definition is what matters for the effective type, unless the buffer was dynamically allocated. If `struct libusb_control_setup` contains a member of “one of the aforementioned types” relative to that original definition, then accessing as this structure type satisfies the penultimate condition of the aliasing rule. The aliasing rule is broken in this regard as the compiler has no way of knowing the effective type when compiling this function separately.

Comment: `but since this is code from respectable project` it does not proof anything. As @dbush mentioned `memcpy` should be used. Most compilers will not actually call the `memcpy`

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Yes, you are right. I have deleted my comment.

Comment: @0___________: Compiler configurations suitable for what one is doing should be used.  The Standard does not require that all conforming implementations be suitable for all purposes, nor that `memcpy` be usable as a catch-all data transformation tool, since `memcpy` may set the Effective Type of its destination to match that of the source.   Further, neither clang nor gcc reliably handles the provision in the Effective Type rules that says that actions which set the Effective Type of storage will only do so until the next time the storage is modified,

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @dbush answer

> Regarding the provided example, that's how I would have done it, but
> since this is code from respectable project which is obviously used in
> a lot of places I'm not sure what to think about it.

Pointer punning is used by many programmers, who think that is safe because it works on their computers. Many programmers also think that using `memcpy` will make their code less efficient and more memory greedy.

In most circumstances (when possible of course) the compiler will optimize out the `memcpy` call

example:

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    double b;
    int (*callback)(int);
}mt;

int foo(char *ptr, int par)
{
    mt m;

    memcpy(&m, ptr, sizeof(m));

    printf("%f\n", m.b);
    m.callback(par);
    return m.a;
}
```

The x86 compiler produces code :

```
.LC0:
        .string "%f\n"
foo:
        push    rbp
        mov     ebp, esi
        sub     rsp, 32
        movdqu  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+16]
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp], xmm1
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+16], rax
        mov     eax, 1
        call    printf
        mov     edi, ebp
        call    [QWORD PTR [rsp+16]]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp]
        add     rsp, 32
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

But ARM Cortex M0 will call the `memcpy` as an unaligned version of the pointer will cause hardware exception.

```
.LC0:
        .ascii  "%f\012\000"
foo:
        push    {r4, lr}
        movs    r4, r1
        sub     sp, sp, #32
        movs    r1, r0
        movs    r2, #24
        add     r0, sp, #8
        bl      memcpy
        ldr     r2, [sp, #16]
        ldr     r3, [sp, #20]
        ldr     r0, .L3
        str     r2, [sp]
        str     r3, [sp, #4]
        bl      printf
        movs    r0, r4
        ldr     r3, [sp, #24]
        blx     r3
        ldr     r0, [sp, #8]
        add     sp, sp, #32
        pop     {r4, pc}
.L3:
        .word   .LC0
```

Comment: Pointer punning *will* be safe on implementations which specify that they will process such constructs "in a documented manner characteristic of the environment", and which target environments whose documented behaviors match what the programmer expects.  Using memcpy may be good to deal with alignment issues, but jumping through hoops purely for aliasing issues not so much.  Even if one jumps through hoops to write strictly conforming program which is functionally equivalent to code that could do a task more easily using punning, clang and gcc will sometimes miscompile it anyway.

Comment: The `memcpy()` call could have a significant performance impact in an ARM Cortex M0 application. In some cases, performance may outweigh standard conformance as long as there are ways to ensure that the resulting functionality is correct.

Comment: @nielsen but you have to be sure that the pointer passed is correctly aligned. Otherwise, the program invokes the HF and performance will be the least important problem for you.

Comment: @0___________ Yes, it is definitely a requirement that the buffer is known to be created such that all alignment requirements of the structure are fulfilled (ruling out HF should be covered by "ensuring that the functionality is correct"). On the other hand, *if* alignment is ensured, I find it difficult to imagine what could go wrong in a decoding function like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use of a structure or union type to read or write data from an externally-supplied character buffer poses two potential problems:

1. The Standard allows implementations whose users would never need to access storage as different types and different times broad license to assume that programs won't perform such accesses.  While it explicitly recognizes the existence of implementations that guarantee that all accesses to objects will be treated as accesses to the underlying storage using the precise semantics of the hosting execution environment (see N1570 5.1.2.3 paragraph 9) whether or not the Standard would require them to do so, and allows conforming (but not strictly) conforming programs to exclusively target such implementations, it makes no distinction between implementations that offer such guarantees and those that don't.
2. The behavior of casting a pointer to a struct or union type only has defined behavior if the pointer would satisfy the strictest alignment requirements of every member thereof.  If the struct or union has a member whose alignment requirement isn't satisfied by the pointer, casting to the struct or union type will invoke Undefined Behavior, and on some real-world implementations is likely to produce erroneous code *even if the pointer satisfies the alignment requirement for all members that are actually used*.

The first issue can be dealt with by using a compiler configuration appropriate to the task at hand.  The second, however, should be borne in mind even if one uses the `-fno-strict-aliasing dialect`.  Given something like:

```
#include <string.h>
struct foo { short x, y; int z; } sf;
void test1(void *p)
{
    memcpy(&sf, p, sizeof (struct foo));
}
void test2(void *p)
{
    struct foo *foop = p;
    memcpy(&sf, foop, sizeof (struct foo));
}
```

When targeting the Cortex-M0, clang will generate code for `test1` which will be much less efficient (almost a 4:1 speed and space penalty) than `test2` in the case where `p` is word-aligned, but the code for `test2` will fail if p isn't word-aligned while the slower code for `test1` will work regardless.

Thus, even when using `memcpy`, a decision of whether to cast a pointer to a structure type should consider what is known about the alignment.  Such a cast may greatly improve efficiency if the alignment is known, but cause a program to crash if it isn't.

Comment: So in short use memcpy and never cast directly.
And the code I mentioned above is incorrect unsless `-fno-strict-aliasing` is used, and even then it may not be correct?

Comment: @antun: Any code which involves reinterpreting storage should use `-fno-strict-aliasing`, since without that flag neither clang nor gcc will correctly handle all of the corner cases where memory gets recycled as different types, even when that is done in unambiguously strictly conforming fashion.  Using a 16-bit or larger type to read an object of unknown alignment will make code hardware-dependent  Whether or not that is a problem depends upon the range of platforms upon which anyone might want to use the code.  For something simple like reading a 16-bit value (which is all I see...

Comment: ...being accessed through the converted pointer) I think a purpose-designed "load possibly-unaligned 16-bit value" function using two loads and a shift would be a better choice than `memcpy`.

Comment: I see what you are saying. But if we wish to have really portable code which can be easily dropped to other projects using different compilers, some of which are not even using gcc/arm or using completely different architectures, I assume that the only right way is to use memcpy. And that's what I'm aiming at, I would like to know if the code above is really C compliant if we do not assume anything about compiler flags or architecture, or should it be rewritten to use memcpy.

Comment: @antun: There is often a substantial difference between the amount of effort necessary to write code that almost all compilers for commonplace platforms can be configured to process, versus writing code which will work interchangeably on all conforming C implementations including the most obscure ones.  If code uses a purpose-designed function to e.g. fetch a 16-bit little-endian value from a pointer of unknown alignment, the function can be written in 100% portable fashion, or tweaked for particular target platforms to run more efficiently on them without the calling code having to care.

Answer (score 0):

Libusb is written in C.

In order to cope with C strict aliasing rules, it is enough to write your application in a different language. Assembly, Haskell, Java, Rust, and even C++ (yes!) are all good. C strict aliasing rules do not apply to these languages.

So from the libusb point of view, the `buffer` parameter just magically appears out of nowhere, with no C objects whatsoever living in it.

Does the C standard place any requirements on this situation? Of course not. The standard allows C programs to interact with code written in other languages, but no specific rules are laid out. So this is undefined behaviour as far as the C standard is concerned. Let me reiterate: *any interaction of C with other languages is UB*. However, for some reason, even the most stubborn of C purists are somehow content with this specific kind of undefined behaviour, so we can assume this is OK.

But what if you really like C?

You could write your code in C, then use a C++ compiler (remember, no strict aliasing rules for C-to-C++ interactions). But this is too risky. The languages have diverged and the same constructs sometimes have different meanings in them. So this is not a scalable approach.

There wasn't a solution—until now. But I have invented a solution, and I hereby release my invention to the public domain.

Here it is: write your client application in a new language called C??. This language ls not very different from C. Its standard can be obtained by taking the C standard (any version you want) and replacing all relevant occurrences of the identifier `C` with `C??`. (Careful, don't replace all occurrences, or you will make some code examples invalid). There are several free and commercial compilers for this language readily available (gcc, clang, and msvc are all more or less competent C?? compilers).

The C?? language has its own strict aliasing rules, but of course they only apply to C?? programs. Whenever an object is created in C?? and its address is passed to C code (or vice versa), there are no rules that dictate how similar or dissimilar the relevant C and C?? types should be. They are never "the same type" or "compatible types" or anything like that, because there are no rules that govern compatibility of C and C?? types. So one can be, say, `libusb_control_setup` and the other one, say, `char[128]`, and we are not better or worse off compared to the situation where both types are called `libusb_control_setup`.

So yes, we have traded one kind of UB for another. One that gets people all riled up, for one that nobody has ever said anything against. I'd say it's a good deal.